Update IP Whois Objects using RIPE.net API
So I've searched around RIPE.net and other sources, haven't been able to find an example of how I can do this, as I am not an ASN operator etc.
I've essentially got my RIPE.net Account added to some IPs as so:
mnt-by:          XXXX-MNT

so I am able to query a IP on the DB, then update it as I have many times before, but I would like to do this programmatically, which is why I want to know how to update it using the RIPE.net API.
Some of the things I wish to update, is the COUNTRY for one of my IPs, the NETNAME, and add remarks.
I would appreciate some assistance on the getting the right API endpoint for this, thanks a lot.
